# ruby - how do I get input while print to somewhere else?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, input, terminal, output

I wrote ruby script like below.
`puts a` and echo of `gets` are mixed.
how can I arrange print value 'a' on terminal position 0,0
and gets on position y=10, x=0?
thanks.

```
Thread.new do 
    a = 1
    loop do
        puts a
        a += 1
        sleep 0.5
    end
end

loop do
    gets
end
```

Comment: Did you try [ncurses](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/)?

Comment: I tried curses not ncurses. is it different?

Comment: If you tried curses, what problems did you get? It allows you to write to and read from the screen. Not by `puts` though

Comment: when I type, I lost my cursor.

Comment: You should operate by `addstr` and `getch` methods of `curses`, not by `puts` and `gets`.

Comment: if I use getch, do I have to implement backspace, delete, home, end, arrow, caps lock, shift function?

Comment: @taeyun: Yes, you do, if you use io/wait. It's simple enough, though. You just need to dive into terminal escape codes. No, you don't, if you use curses or a variation thereof.

Comment: will you be more specific? how can I use curses library to avoid many hand implementation?